How to show react-rnd resize handles only when clicked?
I am trying to create a Editable text component using react-rnd library , which is resizable and draggable.
When the component is being resized, the resize handles are getting hidden. I don't want that; I want it to behave like Canva , where the resize handles are visible while resizing.
Below is one approach I tried :
'use client'

// components/ResizableText.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Rnd } from 'react-rnd';
import { StepForwardOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
const ResizableText: React.FC = () => {
    const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState<number>(16); // Initial font size

    const handleResize = (direction: string, width: number, height: number) => {
        // Calculate new font size based on the width of the resizable element

        if (direction !== "left" && direction !== "right") {
            const newFontSize = Math.max(8, Math.min(72, width / 10)); // Limit font size between 8 and 72
            setFontSize(newFontSize);
        }

    }

    return (
        <Rnd
            className=' rnd hover:border-2 '
            default={{
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: 200,
                height: 100,
            }}
            minWidth={50}
            minHeight={50}
            bounds="window"
            resizeHandleClasses={{
                bottomRight: 'resize-handle',
                bottomLeft: 'resize-handle',
                topRight: 'resize-handle',
                topLeft: 'resize-handle',
                right: 'resize-handle',
                left: 'resize-handle',
                top: 'resize-handle',
                bottom: 'resize-handle',
            }} onResize={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
                handleResize(direction, ref.offsetWidth, ref.offsetHeight);
            }}
        >
            <div className='overflow-hidden' style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <h1 suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable style={{ fontSize: `${fontSize}px`, outline: 'none' }}>
                    Editable Text
                </h1>
            </div>
        </Rnd>
    );
};

export default ResizableText;


This is my CSS:
.rnd:focus-within .resize-handle {
  display: block;
}

.resize-handle {
  display: none;
}

.resize-handle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(106, 0, 255);
}
 

